# Y-a-t-il une différence entre "piquer au vif" et "piquer sur le vif" ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Y-a-t-il une différence entre "piquer au vif" et "piquer sur le vif" ?

Je sais que "piquer au vif" veut dire "irriter vivement; atteindre, blesser l'amour-propre (de quelqu'un)".

Dans la phrase "Ils voulaient me piquer **sur le** vif" y-a-t-il quelque différence de sens ?

Comment: Où as-tu vu ou entendu « piquer sur le vif » ? Personnellement je ne l'ai jamais rencontré. Quand je lis ça je n'arrive à voir que le sens concret : « piquer (par exemple avec une aiguille) sur celui qui est vivant ». Sinon il y a l'expression [« prendre sur le vif »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sur_le_vif).

Comment: @ None merci beaucoup !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Piquer sur le vif* est environ **cinq cents** fois plus rare que *piquer au vif* avec en général la même signification, même si on peut trouver quelques exemples où il est mis pour *prendre sur vif*.

[image]

> *Quoy que tu ayes accumulé injures sur injures pour outrager son honneur, si ne s'en sentirait-il point offencé, ny piqué sur le vif, quand il vivroit.* Nicolas Pasquier, *Lettres*, 1623.

> *Chacun est là, piqué sur le vif ... La jeune fille trouve instantanément le mot qui fait image [...]*, Jean-Jaques Gautier, *La Demoiselle du Pont-aux-Anes*, 1950.

> *Un seul protagoniste, père de neuf enfants, un charpentier de Ville (Marne) , piqué sur le vif par la remarque désobligeante d'une avorteuse [...]*, Anne-Marie Sohn, *Chrysalides*, 1996.

> *Mais aux mots d'insipide galanterie, l'abbé, piqué sur le vif, s'apprête à répondre, lorsqu'un nouveau personnage sort du cercle et fait un pas en avant [...]*, Dominique Fernandez, *Porporino*, 1976.

Sens 2, *pris sur le vif* : littéralement *pris sur le vivant*, proche du *live* anglais (en direct) :

> *Tout à été vu et entendu, piqué sur le vif, chaque chose est bien à sa place [...]*, E.J., *Bulletin littéraire et bibliographique, Bibliothèque universelle et Revue suisse*, p 667, 1902

Cette forme est tellement rare qu'il vaut probablement mieux éviter de l'utiliser.

Comment: Merci beaucoup !